# What visa for a visiting researcher (PhD student) in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, study

I am a Tunisian PhD student, in the last year of PhD, I found a lab from UK and I want to do a visiting research PhD with them (during 7 months), PS: I will finance myself. I don't have a big background about the visa. Thus, I have a question Which type of visa I should applied for ?

Comment: Have you tried using this tool to find the available options https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa?